# Get the last three chars from any string - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to take the last three chracters of any string and save it as another String variable. I'm having some tough time with my thought process.

```
String word = "onetwotwoone"
int length = word.length();
String new_word = id.getChars(length-3, length, buffer, index);
```

I don't know how to use the getChars method when it comes to buffer or index. Eclipse is making me have those in there. Any suggestions?

Comment: The buffer is a `char[]` where the characters will go, and index is the start of that array where you want to start the copy.  Just create a char[] of size 3 and set index to 0.  Although substring would probably be better

Comment: agree with mark convert to char[] (String.toCharArray() and then print last 3)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Why not just `String substr = word.substring(word.length() - 3)`?

**Update**

Please make sure you check that the `String` is at least 3 characters long before calling `substring()`:

```
if (word.length() == 3) {
  return word;
} else if (word.length() > 3) {
  return word.substring(word.length() - 3);
} else {
  // whatever is appropriate in this case
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("word has fewer than 3 characters!");
}
```

Comment: Might have to be careful with strings with less than three characters, I think negative inputs will return the original string (could be wrong about that), which may or may not be acceptable for what they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @celestialorb: a negative index will cause an exception, according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

Comment: @celestialorb, Thanks for the mention, anyway the initial code from the question also has to handle exceptions, so I wasn't thinking about this issue.

Comment: Negative index is easily avoided using `Math.max()` like this `String substr = word.substring(Math.max(0, word.length() - 3));`

Comment: why answering questions with questions? you don't expect that he has a reason for not using the substring. probably he doesn't know that yet.

Comment: The first two _if_ statements could be condensed into a single one: ```if (word.length() >= 3)```

Answer (score 41):

I would consider `right` method from `StringUtils` class from Apache Commons Lang:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#right(java.lang.String,%20int)

It is safe. You will not get `NullPointerException` or `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Example usage:

`StringUtils.right("abcdef", 3)`

You can find more examples under the above link.

Answer (score 16):

Here's some terse code that does the job using regex:

```
String last3 = str.replaceAll(".*?(.?.?.?)?$", "$1");
```

This code returns *up to* 3; if there are less than 3 it just returns the string.

This is how to do it *safely* without regex in one line:

```
String last3 = str == null || str.length() < 3 ? 
    str : str.substring(str.length() - 3);
```

By "safely", I mean without throwing an exception if the string is nulls or shorter than 3 characters (all the other answers are not "safe").

---

The above code is identical in effect to this code, if you prefer a more verbose, but potentially easier-to-read form:

```
String last3;
if (str == null || str.length() < 3) {
    last3 = str;
} else {
    last3 = str.substring(str.length() - 3);
}
```

Comment: Possible, but quite difficult to understand with its ternary operator and lack of parentheses. So I'd advise against that here. -1.

Comment: @MvG so this answer is "not helpful"? (That's what a -1 vote means). Why is the use of ternary syntax not helpful? And where would you put brackets? On the contrary, I think this answer is helpful, especially considering all the others would explode if handed a null or a short input.

Comment: Not helpful because I believe (sorry if I'm wrong there) that most users who struggle with how to extract a substring from a given string, will be in way over their head trying to read your code. Checking length is all very fine, but at this level I'd consider more verbose solutions helpful, and cryptic solutions only confusing. As to parentheses: I'd write this `… = ((… || …) ? … : …)`. The line wrap you added makes things a lot better, too.

Comment: After looong time, but still would like to comment. @Bohemian's is perfect and should accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

`String newString = originalString.substring(originalString.length()-3);`

Answer (score 5):

```
public String getLastThree(String myString) {
    if(myString.length() > 3)
        return myString.substring(myString.length()-3);
    else
        return myString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the `String` composed of the last three characters, you can use [`substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

```
String new_word = word.substring(word.length() - 3);
```

If you actually want them as a character array, you should write

```
char[] buffer = new char[3];
int length = word.length();
word.getChars(length - 3, length, buffer, 0);
```

The first two arguments to [`getChars`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char%5B%5D,%20int%29) denote the portion of the string you want to extract. The third argument is the array into which that portion will be put. And the last argument gives the position in the buffer where the operation starts.

If the string has less than three characters, you'll get an exception in either of the above cases, so you might want to check for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method I use to get the last xx of a string:

```
public static String takeLast(String value, int count) {
    if (value == null || value.trim().length() == 0 || count < 1) {
        return "";
    }

    if (value.length() > count) {
        return value.substring(value.length() - count);
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
String testStr = "this is a test string";
String last1 = takeLast(testStr, 1); //Output: g
String last4 = takeLast(testStr, 4); //Output: ring
```

Answer (score 1):

This method would be helpful :

```
String rightPart(String text,int length)
{
    if (text.length()<length) return text;
    String raw = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        raw += text.toCharArray()[text.length()-i];
    }
    return new StringBuilder(raw).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getChars` string method does not return a value, instead it dumps its result into your buffer (or destination) array.  The index parameter describes the start offset in your destination array.

Try this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_getchars.htm) for a more verbose description of the `getChars` method.

I agree with the others on this, I think substring would be a better way to handle what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a substring

```
String word = "onetwotwoone"
int lenght = word.length(); //Note this should be function.
String numbers = word.substring(word.length() - 3);
```

Comment: it should be `word.length()`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way for "insufficient string length or null" save:

```
String numbers = defaultValue();
try{
   numbers = word.substring(word.length() - 3);
} catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Insufficient String length");
}
```

Comment: Please do not provide "code only" answers. It may not help others who find this post. Please provide a brief description of what your code is doing and why it helps with the OP's problem.

Comment: Done Mike...feel free to improve if required.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return the x amount of characters from the end.

```
public static String lastXChars(String v, int x) {
    return v.length() <= x ? v : v.substring(v.length() - x);
}
```

//usage

```
System.out.println(lastXChars("stackoverflow", 4)); // flow
```